# edit variable observations based on criteria but leave other observations unchanged that don't meet the edit criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe which I am trying to change some observations...:

```
lease<-c('190', '190', '190', '190', '191', '191', '191', '191')
year<-c(2016, 2017, 2016, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2018)
dive_type<-c('35m','35m', '35m','35m', '35m','35m', '35m','35m')
df=data.frame(lease, year, dive_type)
```

My code:

```
dfi<-df%>%
   mutate(dive_type = case_when(lease==190 & (year %in% c(2016, 2017))~ 
 'Farm dive'))
```

the result:

```
lease  year   dive_type
<fctr> <dbl>  <chr>                  
190    2016   Farm dive     
190    2017   Farm dive     
190    2016   Farm dive     
190    2018   NA        
191    2016   NA        
191    2017   NA        
191    2016   NA        
191    2018   NA
```

The problem is the NAs in dive_type, I would like these to remain unchanged from the original dataframe (i.e. '35m'). This is just an example of a much more complex data set with many levels of dive_type and other variables so it wouldn't be convenient to write code to repopulated the NAs. Help with the code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `TRUE` part in `case_when` which would include all the cases when none of the above conditions match.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(dive_type = case_when(lease==190 & (year %in% c(2016, 2017)) ~ 'Farm dive', 
                           TRUE ~ as.character(dive_type)))


#  lease year dive_type
#1   190 2016 Farm dive
#2   190 2017 Farm dive
#3   190 2016 Farm dive
#4   190 2018       35m
#5   191 2016       35m
#6   191 2017       35m
#7   191 2016       35m
#8   191 2018       35m
```